# Look back based on X days an get col values based on condition spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following DF:

```
--------------------------------
|Id |Date       |Value   |cond  |
|-------------------------------|
|1  |2022-08-03 |     100| 1    |                         
|1  |2022-08-04 |     200| 2    |
|1  |2022-08-05 |     150| 3    |
|1  |2022-08-06 |     300| 4    |
|1  |2022-08-07 |     400| 5    |
|1  |2022-08-08 |     150| 6    |
|1  |2022-08-09 |     500| 7    |
|1  |2022-08-10 |     150| 8    |
|1  |2022-08-11 |     150| 9    |
|1  |2022-08-12 |     700| 1    |
|1  |2022-08-13 |     800| 2    |
|1  |2022-08-14 |     150| 2    |
|1  |2022-08-15 |     300| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-16 |     200| 1    |
|1  |2022-08-17 |     150| 3    |
|1  |2022-08-18 |     150| 1    |
|1  |2022-08-19 |     250| 4    |
|1  |2022-08-20 |     150| 5    |
|1  |2022-08-21 |     400| 6    |    
|2  |2022-08-03 |     100| 1    |
|2  |2022-08-04 |     200| 2    |
|2  |2022-08-05 |     150| 1    |
|2  |2022-08-06 |     300| 1    |
|2  |2022-08-07 |     400| 1    |
|2  |2022-08-08 |     150| 1    |
|2  |2022-08-09 |     125| 1    |
|2  |2022-08-10 |     150| 1    |
|2  |2022-08-11 |     150| 3    |
|2  |2022-08-12 |     170| 6    |
|2  |2022-08-13 |     150| 7    |
|2  |2022-08-14 |     150| 8    |
|2  |2022-08-15 |     300| 1    |
|2  |2022-08-16 |     150| 9    |
|2  |2022-08-17 |     150| 0    |
|2  |2022-08-18 |     400| 1    |
|2  |2022-08-19 |     150| 1    |
|2  |2022-08-20 |     500| 1    |
|2  |2022-08-21 |     150| 1    |
--------------------------------
```

And this one:

```
---------------------
|Date       | cond  |
|-------------------|
|2022-08-03 |  1    |
|2022-08-04 |  2    |
|2022-08-05 |  1    |
|2022-08-06 |  1    |
|2022-08-07 |  1    |
|2022-08-08 |  1    |
|2022-08-09 |  1    |
|2022-08-10 |  1    |
|2022-08-11 |  3    |
|2022-08-12 |  6    |
|2022-08-13 |  8    |
|2022-08-14 |  9    |
|2022-08-15 |  1    |
|2022-08-16 |  2    |
|2022-08-17 |  2    |
|2022-08-18 |  0    |
|2022-08-19 |  1    |
|2022-08-20 |  3    |
|2022-08-21 |  1    |
--------------------
```

My expected output is:

```
-------------------------------
|Id |Date       |Avg   |Count|
|-----------------------------|
|1  |2022-08-03 |     0| 0    |                         
|1  |2022-08-04 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-05 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-06 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-07 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-08 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-09 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-10 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-11 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-12 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-13 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-14 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-15 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-16 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-17 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-18 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-19 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-20 |     0| 0    |
|1  |2022-08-21 |     0| 0    |    
|2  |2022-08-03 |     0| 0    |
|2  |2022-08-04 |     0| 0    |
|2  |2022-08-05 |     0| 1    |
|2  |2022-08-06 |     0| 2    |
|2  |2022-08-07 |     0| 3    |
|2  |2022-08-08 | 237,5| 4    |
|2  |2022-08-09 |   250| 4    |
|2  |2022-08-10 |243,75| 4    |
|2  |2022-08-11 |     0| 0    |
|2  |2022-08-12 |     0| 0    |
|2  |2022-08-13 |     0| 0    |
|2  |2022-08-14 |     0| 0    |
|2  |2022-08-15 |206,25| 4    |
|2  |2022-08-16 |     0| 0    |
|2  |2022-08-17 |     0| 0    |
|2  |2022-08-18 |     0| 0    |
|2  |2022-08-19 |243,75| 4    |
|2  |2022-08-20 |     0| 0    |
|2  |2022-08-21 | 337,5| 4    |
-------------------------------
```

The algorithm is:

1. Verify if  `Date` and `Cond` are the same in the first and second DFs.
2. If the condition is true, I need to lookback on DF1 four days (D-1, D-2, D-3, D-4) based on `Cond` and calculate the Average(`Avg`) and count of this values. If I have more then 4 days I need to use the top 4 values to calculate the `Avg` and `Count` is going to be always 4 in this case.

Example situations based on the inputs:

1. `Id = 1`, `Date = 2022-08-08`

- `Count` is 0 because the condition is false, then `Avg` is 0 too.

2. `Id = 2`, `Date = 2022-08-08`

- `Count` is 4 because the condition is true, then I get values of `2022-08-07`, `2022-08-06`, `2022-08-05`, `2022-08-03`. I exclude `2022-08-04` because `Cond` value there is 2, and the Date I'm using as reference `Cond` is 1.

3. `Id = 2`, `Date = 2022-08-07`

- `Count` is 3 because the condition is true, but I have only the 3 values before that date, so I can't calculate the `Avg` since I need four values, so in that case `Avg` is zero.

I tried to use window function, but with no success. I was able to achieve the output DF using SQL (Joins with Outter Apply). But spark doesn't have outter apply. So, my doubts are:

1. How to generate the output DF.
2. What is the best the way the generate the output DF.

MVCE to generate the input DFs in pyspark:

```
data_1=[
    ("1","2022-08-03",100,1),
    ("1","2022-08-04",200,2),
    ("1","2022-08-05",150,3),
    ("1","2022-08-06",300,4),
    ("1","2022-08-07",400,5),
    ("1","2022-08-08",150,6),
    ("1","2022-08-09",500,7),
    ("1","2022-08-10",150,8),
    ("1","2022-08-11",150,9),
    ("1","2022-08-12",700,1),
    ("1","2022-08-13",800,2),
    ("1","2022-08-14",150,2),
    ("1","2022-08-15",300,0),
    ("1","2022-08-16",200,1),
    ("1","2022-08-17",150,3),
    ("1","2022-08-18",150,1),
    ("1","2022-08-19",250,4),
    ("1","2022-08-20",150,5),
    ("1","2022-08-21",400,6),
    ("2","2022-08-03",100,1),
    ("2","2022-08-04",200,2),
    ("2","2022-08-05",150,1),
    ("2","2022-08-06",300,1),
    ("2","2022-08-07",400,1),
    ("2","2022-08-08",150,1),
    ("2","2022-08-09",125,1),
    ("2","2022-08-10",150,1),
    ("2","2022-08-11",150,3),
    ("2","2022-08-12",170,6),
    ("2","2022-08-13",150,7),
    ("2","2022-08-14",150,8),
    ("2","2022-08-15",300,1),
    ("2","2022-08-16",150,9),
    ("2","2022-08-17",150,0),
    ("2","2022-08-18",400,1),
    ("2","2022-08-19",150,1),
    ("2","2022-08-20",500,1),
    ("2","2022-08-21",150,1)
    
]

schema_1 = StructType([
    StructField("Id", StringType(),True),
    StructField("Date", DateType(),True),
    StructField("Value", IntegerType(),True),
    StructField("Cond", IntegerType(),True)
  ])

df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data_1,schema=schema_1)


 data_2 = [
     ("2022-08-03", 1),
     ("2022-08-04", 2),
     ("2022-08-05", 1),
     ("2022-08-06", 1),
     ("2022-08-07", 1),
     ("2022-08-08", 1),
     ("2022-08-09", 1),
     ("2022-08-10", 1),
     ("2022-08-11", 3),
     ("2022-08-12", 6),
     ("2022-08-13", 8),
     ("2022-08-14", 9),
     ("2022-08-15", 1),
     ("2022-08-16", 2),
     ("2022-08-17", 2),
     ("2022-08-18", 0),
     ("2022-08-19", 1),
     ("2022-08-20", 3),
     ("2022-08-21", 1)
 ]

schema_2 = StructType([
    StructField("Date", DateType(),True),
    StructField("Cond", IntegerType(),True)
  ])

df_2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data_2,schema=schema_2)
```

**UPDATE: I updated the question to be more clearly about the conditions to join the DFs!**

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73002153/spark-scala-how-to-group-data-based-on-a-field-with-a-certain-range/73002885#73002885) question, I think it is similar. You can use RDD to solve problem

Comment: What is the point of `df_2`, no new data is being taken from there? Also, Date, Cond, Id needs to be the same in both DFs --> but `df_2` has no Id field?

Comment: Looks like you missed providing `data_1` in your sample code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do a left `join` to get the dates you are interested in.
2. Then use `pyspark.sql.window` to get the values you need into a list and take `size` of this as *Count*.
3. Finally with the help of [`pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate.html) get the *Avg*.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

# cast to date, and rename columns for later use
df_1 = df_1.withColumn("Date", F.col("Date").cast("date"))
df_2 = df_2.withColumn("Date", F.col("Date").cast("date"))
df_2 = df_2.withColumnRenamed("Date", "DateDf2")\
        .withColumnRenamed("Cond", "CondDf2")

# left join 
df = df_1.join(df_2, (df_1.Cond==df_2.CondDf2)&(df_1.Date==df_2.DateDf2), how='left')

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Id", "Cond").orderBy("Date")

# all the magic happens here!
df = (
    # only start counting when "DateDf2" is not null, and put the values into a list
    df.withColumn("value_list", F.when(F.isnull("DateDf2"), F.array()).otherwise(F.collect_list("Value").over(windowSpec.rowsBetween(-4, -1))))
    .withColumn("Count", F.size("value_list"))
    # use aggregate to sum up the list only if the size is 4! and divide by 4 to get average
    .withColumn("Avg", F.when(F.col("count")==4, F.aggregate("value_list", F.lit(0), lambda acc,x: acc+x)/4).otherwise(F.lit(0)))
    .select("Id", "Date", "Avg", "Count")
    .orderBy("Id", "Date")
)
```

Output is:

```
+---+----------+------+-----+
|Id |Date      |Avg   |Count|
+---+----------+------+-----+
|1  |2022-08-03|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-04|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-05|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-06|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-07|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-08|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-09|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-10|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-11|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-12|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-13|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-14|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-15|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-16|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-17|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-18|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-19|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-20|0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-21|0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-03|0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-04|0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-05|0.0   |1    |
|2  |2022-08-06|0.0   |2    |
|2  |2022-08-07|0.0   |3    |
|2  |2022-08-08|237.5 |4    |
|2  |2022-08-09|250.0 |4    |
|2  |2022-08-10|243.75|4    |
|2  |2022-08-11|0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-12|0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-13|0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-14|0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-15|206.25|4    |
|2  |2022-08-16|0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-17|0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-18|0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-19|243.75|4    |
|2  |2022-08-20|0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-21|337.5 |4    |
+---+----------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the attention! I've updated the question changing DF2 since it's not used in `windowSpec` the value of `cond`column in DF2 may be different than `cond` in DF1 sometimes!

Comment: @OdiumPura, and could you update the output also then? Will the output not contain the dates `2022-08-05` and `2022-08-08` as `cond`s are different?

Comment: Also are the timestamps important or only the date. If date, then can cast to `date`, will make the `orderBy` simpler in the window.

Comment: I've updated the question. I changed the valuest a little bit  to be easier to understand my problem (on the past version I've tried to summarize my problem, but with no success since most people were finding it confusing). I've update MVCE too.

Comment: @OdiumPura, finally understood what you want! Updated answer gives the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution for the same

```
Solution:
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df_1= df_1.withColumn("Date",F.col("Date").cast("timestamp"))
df_2= df_2.withColumn("Date",F.col("Date").cast("timestamp"))
window_spec =  Window.partitionBy(["Id"]).orderBy("Date")  
four_days_sld_wnd_exl_cuurent_row = Window.partitionBy(["Id"]).orderBy(["rnk"]).rangeBetween(-4, -1)
window_spec_count_cond_ = Window.partitionBy(["Id"]).orderBy(F.unix_timestamp("Date", 'yyyy-MM-dd') / 86400).rangeBetween(-4, -1)
agg_col_cond_ = (F.col("agg") ==0.0)
date_2_col_cond_ = (F.col("Date_2").isNull())
valid_4_days_agg_value =(F.when((~date_2_col_cond_) & (F.size(F.col("date_arrays_with_cond_1"))==4),
                         F.sum(F.col("Value")).over(four_days_sld_wnd_exl_cuurent_row)).otherwise(F.lit(0.0)))

count_cond_ = (F.when(~agg_col_cond_ & ~date_2_col_cond_,F.lit(4))
               .when(agg_col_cond_ & date_2_col_cond_,F.lit(0))
               .otherwise(F.size(F.collect_set(F.col("Date_2")).over(window_spec_count_cond_))))
df_jn = df_1.join(df_2,["Date","Cond"],"left")\
.select(df_1["*"],df_2["Date"].alias("Date_2")).orderBy("Id",df_1["Date"])
filter_having_cond_1=(F.col("Cond") == 1)
cond_columns_matching = (F.col("Date_2").isNull())
df_fnl_with_cond_val_1 = df_jn.filter(filter_having_cond_1)
df_fnl_with_cond_val_other=df_jn.filter(~filter_having_cond_1)\
.withColumn("agg",F.lit(0.0))\
.withColumn("count",F.lit(0))\
.drop("Date_2")

df_fnl_with_cond_val_1 = df_fnl_with_cond_val_1\
.withColumn("rnk",F.row_number().over(window_spec))\
.withColumn("date_arrays_with_cond_1", F.collect_set(F.col("Date")).over(four_days_sld_wnd_exl_cuurent_row))\
.withColumn("agg",valid_4_days_agg_value/4)\
.withColumn("count",count_cond_)\
.drop("date_arrays_with_cond_1","rnk","Date_2")
df_fnl = df_fnl_with_cond_val_1.unionByName(df_fnl_with_cond_val_other)
df_fnl.orderBy(["id","Date"]).show(50,0)
```

kindly upvote if you like my solution .

```
output
+---+-------------------+-----+----+------+-----+
|Id |Date               |Value|Cond|agg   |count|
+---+-------------------+-----+----+------+-----+
|1  |2022-08-03 00:00:00|100  |1   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-04 00:00:00|200  |2   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-05 00:00:00|150  |3   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-06 00:00:00|300  |4   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-07 00:00:00|400  |5   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-08 00:00:00|150  |6   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-09 00:00:00|500  |7   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-10 00:00:00|150  |8   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-11 00:00:00|150  |9   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-12 00:00:00|700  |1   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-13 00:00:00|800  |2   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-14 00:00:00|150  |2   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-15 00:00:00|300  |0   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-16 00:00:00|200  |1   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-17 00:00:00|150  |3   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-18 00:00:00|150  |1   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-19 00:00:00|250  |4   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-20 00:00:00|150  |5   |0.0   |0    |
|1  |2022-08-21 00:00:00|400  |6   |0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-03 00:00:00|100  |1   |0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-04 00:00:00|200  |2   |0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-05 00:00:00|150  |1   |0.0   |1    |
|2  |2022-08-06 00:00:00|300  |1   |0.0   |2    |
|2  |2022-08-07 00:00:00|400  |1   |0.0   |3    |
|2  |2022-08-08 00:00:00|150  |1   |237.5 |4    |
|2  |2022-08-09 00:00:00|125  |1   |250.0 |4    |
|2  |2022-08-10 00:00:00|150  |1   |243.75|4    |
|2  |2022-08-11 00:00:00|150  |3   |0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-12 00:00:00|170  |6   |0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-13 00:00:00|150  |7   |0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-14 00:00:00|150  |8   |0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-15 00:00:00|300  |1   |206.25|4    |
|2  |2022-08-16 00:00:00|150  |9   |0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-17 00:00:00|150  |0   |0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-18 00:00:00|400  |1   |0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-19 00:00:00|150  |1   |243.75|4    |
|2  |2022-08-20 00:00:00|500  |1   |0.0   |0    |
|2  |2022-08-21 00:00:00|150  |1   |337.5 |4    |
+---+-------------------+-----+----+------+-----+
```

Comment: Please do not post multiple answers, edit your first not so an answer with this proper answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why you didn't use `Cond` column in `windowSpec`?

Comment: I ask this because the column `Cond` is the same on the example that I abstracted. But the column cond can be different in some cases. Another doubt is: If column `agg` is numerical, is it possible to get the average of the numerical values of the list columnd? I updated the question! And please, if it possible, delete your answer as comment. Thank you so much! @Deku07

Comment: @OdiumPura currently thinking the scenario.

Comment: @OdiumPura

how would you validate these condition

Verify if Date, Id and Cond are the same in the first and second DFs.

question: I mean to ask there is no Id column present in df_2 . how would you say the same id are being present for both dfs??

Comment: @Deku07 Sorry it's a mismatch. I've updated the question. It's only necessary to validate `Date` and  `Cond`.

Comment: @OdiumPura

for id=1 and date values in ("2022-08-03","2022-08-04") how come the count has become zero  in outcome ?
because count is deriving from joining the two dfs based Date and Cond .

it looks like to me count for the or id=1 and date values in ("2022-08-03","2022-08-04")
should be 1 and 2 respectively .
Please let me know if my understanding is wrong .

Comment: Because I only start to count after validating condition 1. In your example the conditions are ok, so i start to count... in date `2022-08-03` I have no date before with `Cond` 1, so `Count` is zero. On date `2022-08-04` I have 1 date before that but the Cond of that date is 1 when the actual date is 2, so `count` is zero too. Basically i start to count if the join is ok, i don't count based on join. Like I said, the join is the condition to start to count, I use DF 2 only to verify if I start to count or not. If I start, I need to count by the values of DF1

Comment: @OdiumPura

for id=1 and date= "2022-08-04", cond values in both df_1 and df_2 are same . so ideally it should have count=1?
for id=2 . date= "2022-08-04", cond values in both df_1 and df_2 are same as well 

Could you please edit the question and explain more clearly in  with example ?

Comment: Like I Said in my above comment, I just use DF2 to validate if I need to count. So if the values are the same in both DF, I start to count BASED on DF1 Values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247265/discussion-between-odiumpura-and-deku07).

Comment: @Deku07, you can maybe use a left join on df1 to df2 based on date and cond, and start to count where this join os satisfied.

Comment: @OdiumPura
i have another question regarding the agg value .

for id=2 and date="2022-08-03" till "2022-08-07" all the cond values are being matched
so , why we are not taking the avg for the records id=2 and date="2022-08-07"
the avg value should be 750/4 ??

Comment: @Deku07, because I only calculate the `Avg` when I have four dates before. In this case you appointed we have only 3. On 2022-08-04 `Cond` is 2, so I start count only in 2022-08-08 for `Cond` 1.

Comment: @OdiumPura

for id=2 and date="2022-08-07" as ref .
all the records starting from "2022-08-03 till ref has matched the Cond of df_2.
so my question is that why we are not calculating the avg for ref records and take previous 4 values to calculate avg ?

and 
FYI "2022-08-04" for id=2 df_1 cond is same as df_2 for the same date="2022-08-04"

Could you add these to this question ? looks like so much nuances.

Comment: @Deku07 I moved the question to a private chat due the extended discussion.